# How can I select the cropped image in fabric js

Tags: html, html5-canvas, fabricjs

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        canvas{
            border:1px solid #ccc;
        }

        .canvas-container{
            float: left;
            left: 20px; 
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id='canvas' width='500' height='600' ></canvas>
<canvas id='C2' width='500' height='600'></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fabric.js"></script>
<script>
    (function() {
      var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
      fabric.Object.prototype.transparentCorners = false;

      var radius = 300;

      fabric.Image.fromURL('./images/Chrysanthemum.jpg', function(img) {
        img.scale(0.4).set({
          left: 10,
          top: 100,
          angle: 0,
          clipTo: function (ctx) {
            ctx.rect(-250, -250, 400, 400);
          }
        });
        canvas.add(img).setActiveObject(img);
        console.log(canvas.getActiveObject());
      });
    })();
</script>
</body>


----------


</html>
```

//the code above;

Now the active object size is the same as the image which has not been cropped;
But if there is any way to make the cropped image to be selected.Means the smaller size which will be selected in a smaller size.
thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clip is not meant for that effect:
If you desire some cropping better go with pattern trick if your cropping differs from what the attribute preserverveAspectRatio allows you.
(basically crop in center, crop left crop right, both for x and y axis).

As you see instead of image i create a rect with desired dimensions, then i use the img loaded to create a pattern that will fill the rect.
You can then use offsetX and offsetY on pattern to modify the part of image visible.

offsets are accessible trought:

```
rect.fill.offsetX
rect.fill.offsetY
```

```js
    (function() {
      var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
      fabric.Object.prototype.transparentCorners = false;

      var radius = 300;

      fabric.Image.fromURL('http://fabricjs.com/assets/pug.jpg', function(img) {
        var rect = new fabric.Rect({width: 400, height: 400});
        var pattern = new fabric.Pattern({source: img.getElement(), offsetX: -20, offsetY: -50});
        rect.scale(0.4).set({
          left: 10,
          top: 100,
          angle: 0,
          fill: pattern,
        });
        canvas.add(rect).setActiveObject(rect);
      });
    })();
```

```css
canvas{
  border:1px solid #ccc;
}

.canvas-container{
  float: left;
  left: 20px; 
}
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas' width='500' height='600' ></canvas>
<canvas id='C2' width='500' height='600'></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://fabricjs.com/lib/fabric.js"></script>
```